# I need to convert UTC date and time based on the local timezone using moment.js, how to convert date from UTC to timezone in html

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, moment-timezone

The code below is displaying date in UTC format not in local timezone.

```html
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index" class="table-width__26">
  {{moment(element.CREATED_DATE).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}} {{'at'}}
  {{ getTime(element.CREATED_DATE,timezone)}} 
  {{ moment.tz([2012,0],timezone).format('z').substr(0, 1) + moment.tz([2012,0],timezone).format('z').substr(2)}}
</mat-cell>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can find your timezone name you can use at below:

```
moment(1369266934311).tz(' Melikgazi/Kayseri').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```